# Create Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I followed the tutorial [Create Linux Virtual Machine](https://%20Ray%20Madigan%20%3Craymond.madigan@gmail.com%3E%2011:34%20AM%20(0%20minutes%20ago)%20to%20me%20%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-cli) and everything seems correct, what do I know since this is my first attempt.  I can't see whats wrong, I can ssh to it and run things, etc.

The issue I have is that I can't ping the public ip address.  The prompt just hangs.  At the end of the tutorial it asks to view a website on the page, and the browser just times out?

Is there something I should look at?

The tutorial creates a website with nginx and I have never used this, but it expects port 80 to be open.  I added port 80 open for the Network Security Group.

I eventually will use Tomcat at port 8080 so I installed and opened port 8080 in the Network security group.

If I try to connect over port 80: ipAddress:80 ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
if I ssh to the vm and use ps aux | grep nginx i get a response like

```
root      7809  0.0  0.0 116528  1400 ?        Ss   20:56   0:00 
    nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;

www-data  7810  0.0  0.0 116880  2576 ?        S    20:56   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

The server is running.

if I try ipAddress:8080 I get the tomcat default web page.  I can't figure out why nginx doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ping wont work. you need to open up website port on the NSG and on your linux box. you can use this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

Comment: I did this, I created a network resource group, created the inbound rule and associated it with my virtual machine.   The response is the same, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: I marked this as correct as it was used and I can get Tomcat to run.

Answer (score 0):

ping is disabled in Azure for public facing IPs

regarding the ports you need to consider two things, first as you mention the NSG has to enable the traffic for the ports of interest, its important to consider that you can have NSGs at the NIC and Vnet levels, please review which one do you have, secondly once the NSG has been opened there has to be a listening service on the VM, you mention that the tutorial tells you to use port 80 but then looks like tomcat uses 8080 instead, I recommend running the following command to verify the listening ports at the OS level

sudo netstat -plnt

please let me know if this helps

Comment: I ran the command you suggested and it verified that the correct ports had listeners.  For some reason I don't understand I have 2 NSG's setup for the VM.  Can I just make one and be sure all of the open ports are enabled?

Comment: just to make sure, the command shows the same listening ports on the VM that you opened on the NSG correct? for the NSG question is that regarding what I mentioned before or did you find other NSGs? I would also like to ask you to test this, if the port you are looking to use is 8080 for example, run the following command on the SSH session Telnet 127.0.0.1 8080 please let me know what happens after that

Comment: Much of the stuff in the dash board was added by someone other then me.  Since there is no road map, no way to know what is actually needed up front, it is hard to know where the other NSG came from.  All I know now is that I can't ssh into the VM where I could yesterday.  All of a sudden some security recommendations appeared, I followed one to see what it was and it told me I had to add NSG to a subnet.  I may have tapped it, but the process ran all night anbd I now can't ssh into the vm.

Comment: Hello, please reach out to me @ AzCommunity@microsoft.com with your subscription ID so we can have a look at it, seems that this is going to require deeper troubleshooting